# Convercion de una ruta absoluta a una relativa en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Cómo convertir una ruta absoluta a relativa pero estoy probando y no me jala este es mi codigo (soy nuevo en `c#`, `asp.net`):

```
public virtual string picture { get; set; }
        String RelativePath = AbsolutePath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);
vista:
<img id="foto" src="@ua.picture"/>
```

Comment: como envias esa ruta relativa a la vista? lo haces por medio de una propiedad en el model o es por el ViewBag

Comment: lo envio por el modelo y en la vista solo llamo a  la variable picture que tiene la ruta del archivo guardada en la base datos pero no lo puedo visualizar me podrias ayudar

Comment: entonces quiere decir que el Model que envias desde el action a la view tiene una propiedad `picture`? si es asi de donde sale `@ua` en la view? porque salvo que estes iterando alguna lista de entidades deberias usar `@Model.picture`

Comment: Perdón me equivoque  es por medio del viewBag, por eso utilizo el @ua.picture,  mi pregunta va relacionado en donde debo convertir picture que es el que recibe la ruta

Comment: Pero si es el `ViewBag` no porque usas `@ua` eso no aplica, deberia ser `@ViewBag.picture`. El picture deberia ser una url, en donde le la carpeta si es una ruta relativa debe estar dentro de la estructura del sitio web

Answer (score 2):

Para que una ruta relativa funcione esta debe encontrarse dentro de la `estructura de carpetas` del sitio web definido en el `hosting` o en el `IIS`

Si pones una archivo de imagen en una ruta por fuera de la carpeta del `sitio web` no funciona la `ruta relativa`, ya que no se podra acceder a esta por medio de la url

Para obtener la carpeta del sitio podrias usa

```
string rutaWebSite = Server.MapPath("~/");
string RelativePath = AbsolutePath.Replace(rutaWebSite, "");
```

[Server.MapPath()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.5)

Comment: Hola podrías ayudarme con un ejercicio, resulta que con un boton genero un documento word a partir de una plantilla, dicha plantilla esta en una carpeta llamada Formatos la cual toma el formato lo edita y lo necesito guardar en otra carpeta, al poner la ruta aboluta funciona pero al tratar de poner una ruta relativa me marca error, algo relacionado con que no esta el directorio. podrias ayudarme a corregirlo. cabe mencionar que para obtener la plantilla puedo hacerlo mediante la url  pero para guardarla no puedo